# Add custom field to DataTable. OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: powershell, datatable, oledbdataadapter

Code works fine until I try to add a custom column using:

```
$datatable.Columns.Add("AD_description1", "String")
```

If I comment the string I can perfectly see results in GridView. But once the string uncommented the gridview displays:

[image]

How do I add a custom field properly?

```
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($QueryString, $ConnectionString)

#Load the DataTable
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$adapter.Fill($datatable)
$datatable.Columns.Add("AD_description1", "String")
$datatable | out-gridview
```

Answer (score 0):

See these results:

```
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($QueryString, $ConnectionString)

#Load the DataTable
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$adapter.Fill($datatable)
$datatable.Columns.Add("AD_description1", "String")
$datatable
# Results
<#
AllowDBNull        : True
AutoIncrement      : False
AutoIncrementSeed  : 0
AutoIncrementStep  : 1
Caption            : AD_description1
ColumnName         : AD_description1
Prefix             : 
DataType           : System.String
DateTimeMode       : UnspecifiedLocal
DefaultValue       : 
Expression         : 
ExtendedProperties : {}
MaxLength          : -1
Namespace          : 
Ordinal            : 0
ReadOnly           : False
Table              : {}
Unique             : False
ColumnMapping      : Element
Site               : 
Container          : 
DesignMode         : False
#>

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($QueryString, $ConnectionString)

#Load the DataTable
$datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$adapter.Fill($datatable)
$datatable.Columns.Add("AD_description1")
$datatable.Columns.Add("SomeString")
$datatable


# Results
<#
AllowDBNull        : True
AutoIncrement      : False
AutoIncrementSeed  : 0
AutoIncrementStep  : 1
Caption            : AD_description1
ColumnName         : AD_description1
Prefix             : 
DataType           : System.String
DateTimeMode       : UnspecifiedLocal
DefaultValue       : 
Expression         : 
ExtendedProperties : {}
MaxLength          : -1
Namespace          : 
Ordinal            : 0
ReadOnly           : False
Table              : {}
Unique             : False
ColumnMapping      : Element
Site               : 
Container          : 
DesignMode         : False

AllowDBNull        : True
AutoIncrement      : False
AutoIncrementSeed  : 0
AutoIncrementStep  : 1
Caption            : SomeString
ColumnName         : SomeString
Prefix             : 
DataType           : System.String
DateTimeMode       : UnspecifiedLocal
DefaultValue       : 
Expression         : 
ExtendedProperties : {}
MaxLength          : -1
Namespace          : 
Ordinal            : 1
ReadOnly           : False
Table              : {}
Unique             : False
ColumnMapping      : Element
Site               : 
Container          : 
DesignMode         : False
#>
```

***References:***

> [Adding Columns to a DataTable | MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable#:%7E:text=You%20create%20DataColumn%20objects%20within%20a%20table%20by,new%20DataColumn%20as%20a%20member%20of%20the%20collection)
>
> [How To Create a DataTable In Powershell](https://www.dbtales.com/how-to-create-a-datatable-in-powershell/#:%7E:text=How%20To%20Create%20a%20DataTable%20In%20Powershell%201,...%207%20Conclusion.%20...%208%20Full%20Example%20Code)